# gridview too slow 12000 records

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, web-services, gridview

i have a clean gridview that i populate in the page_load. this is my code for populating the grid.

```
private void populateGrid()
    {
        test.RH_WebServiceService ligar = new test.RH_WebService();
        test.listaBasePes[] dados = ligar.getAllDadosBase();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dCol1 = new DataColumn("numer", typeof(System.String));
            DataColumn dCol2 = new DataColumn("name", typeof(System.String));
            DataColumn dCol3 = new DataColumn("quadro", typeof(System.String));
            DataColumn dCol4 = new DataColumn("class", typeof(System.String));
            dt.Columns.Add(dCol1);
            dt.Columns.Add(dCol2);
            dt.Columns.Add(dCol3);
            dt.Columns.Add(dCol4);

            for (int i = 0; i <= dados.Length; i++)
            {
                test.desQuadro[] cargo = ligar.getDesQuadro(dados[i].quadro);
                test.desClasse[] classe = ligar.getDesClasse(dados[i].classe);
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row[dCol1] = dados[i].nii;
                row[dCol2] = dados[i].nome;
                row[dCol3] = cargo[0].desquadro;
                row[dCol4] = classe[0].desclasse;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

what im doing in the code above is: im consulting a web service to get all the data from 12000 records and then im grabbing the fields quadro and classe (which are ids) and im using them to consult another webservice which will give me its names instead of IDS. then im saving it into a data table to bind to the gridview later.

i've tried activating paging but it doesnt really matter since the paging that comes with the gridviews loads every single record everytime i change the page.

dont really know if i explained myself correctly since english isn't my main language.
gotta leave now but will pass by here later to check on some answers.

EDIT:my objective is to try and make the page load faster since it takes ages to load

Comment: Why do you request all 12000 records from the database every page? Why not just request the records you need to display the page via a filter on the request (to whatever Database you are querying)?

Comment: Are you paging the grid at all or are you dumping them all onto one huge page?

Comment: The user isn't interested in browsing through 12.000 separate records. Consider paging or another way to filter the data displayed to the user.

Comment: So you're doing 24001 web service calls?  This suggests your web services are too granular.  Is there any way to make getAllDadosBase look up the cargo and classe so you only do 1 web service call?

Comment: Mike Stockdale, no there isnt.

Comment: i tried activating the paging on the gridview but it didnt really help and i read online that even if you have paging active it still reads every row despite not showing all of them.

if i directly databind the variable dados into the gridview it works fine and not slow at all. but that's not really what i want since it would give me ID's of quadro and class and i dont want that, because i need to get its names through other operations.

Ps: if you guys know of any different way of doing this (even if i have to rewrite all the code) guide me. i'd be extremely thankful

Comment: Let the web service do the paging. It is relatively simple to include a record control structure in a web service request and let the service manage the page the user is viewing. Dont this several times and it works pretty well.